# Display: block error - Keep blinking

Tags: javascript, html, css, block

I need when click in button "enviar", it turns "resultado" from "display:none" to "display:block".

html document:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
            function mostraDiv(){       
              resultado.style.display='block';}
</script>
```

---

```
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="button2" onclick="mostraDiv(resultado)" />
```

css document:

```
#resultado{ 
    margin-left:;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-left:10px;

    display:none;
}
```

But I'm having an error.
When I click on "Enviar", "resultado" turns (ON) "block" only by a few miliseconds. I can't resolve this, can you please help?

Comment: It works for me http://jsfiddle.net/DLYtM/

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
function mostraDiv(elementid){       
    document.getElementById(elementid).style.display='block';
}
```

And to use it

```
onclick="mostraDiv('resultado')"
```